# Why are regular expression used in lexical analysis instead of grammars?

Tags: compilers, lexical-analysis

Even though grammars can do what regular expressions do, why are regular expression employed instead of grammars in lexical analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular languages are faster to recognize, and so they are preferred whenever possible. Fortunately, regular expressions are usually good enough for describing the lexemes of a language.

Indeed, in some sense the separation between lexical analysis and parsing is exactly due to this fact, that lexical analysis can be done more efficiently than parsing.